# Network Utils Library

Tags: java, apache

I'm looking for an Apache Commons type of dependency that I can use for simple `ServerSocket` and `Socket` tasks like sending and receiving. I tend to get a lot of errors and it would be easier if there was a `NetworkUtils` that I could use instead. Are there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your domain special enough to justify using something as low level as `Socket`? If not, then `jsonrpc4j` saved me a huge deal of coding effort for sending and receiving objects.